# Finding sum of only deepest leaf nodes in the binary tree?

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-tree

I was solving a question given above and deepest meant only the leaf nodes which are at level = height of the tree. I solved it through an approach which is giving wrong output and i cannot find why while debugging it.

```
int deepsum(TreeNode* root,int h,int sum,int l)
    {
        if(root==NULL)
            return 0;
        if(l==h and root->left==NULL and root->right==NULL)
        {
            sum=root->val;
            return sum;
        }
        int lss=deepsum(root->left,h,sum,l+1);
        int rss=deepsum(root->right,h,sum,l+1);
        return lss+rss;
    }
    int height(TreeNode* root)
    {
         if(root==NULL)
            return 0;
        int ls=deepestLeavesSum(root->left);
        int rs=deepestLeavesSum(root->right);
        return max(ls,rs)+1;
    }
    int deepestLeavesSum(TreeNode* root) {
       int h=height(root);
        int new_sum=deepsum(root,h,0,1);
        return new_sum;
```

The main function here is deepestLeavesSum. The output i am getting is 0 for all the test cases

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but i think that is what i did in the above code. The language used is C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, well, well..

the problem lies in method where you calculating height. your "height" method needs this modification.

```
 int height(TreeNode* root)
{
     if(root==NULL)
        return 0;
    int ls=height(root->left); // 
    int rs=height(root->right);
    return max(ls,rs)+1;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. That was such a poor mistake from my side and for so many days i was not able to look into that.